# How to show a static NON-animated progress bar using CoreGraphics in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

I want to make a static progress bar with no animation at all. I just want the orange part to be filled like [image: this] and this image shows progress of (1 of 3), I would like to know how to accomplish this view for (2 of 3) and finally completed progress bar as in (3 of 3).

Thank you and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a subclass of `UIView`. Give your view a property `var progress = 0`.  Override `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` and draw the 3 segments using `UIBezierPath`, `moveTo`, `lineTo`, `close()`.  Choose your fill color gray or orange based upon the value of `progress` which should be 0-3 and fill the paths.  Add a property observer for `didSet` to `progress` that calls `self.setNeedsDisplay()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a workin, designable class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class StaticLoad: UIView {

    enum Progress {
        case Empty
        case Filled(num: Int)
        case Full
    }

    @IBInspectable public var progressColor: UIColor?  {
        didSet {
            updateColor(progressColor: progressColor ?? tintColor, nonProgressColor: nonProgressColor)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var nonProgressColor: UIColor = .gray {
        didSet {
            updateColor(progressColor: progressColor ?? tintColor, nonProgressColor: nonProgressColor)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var numberOfSteps: Int = 3 {
        didSet {
            redrawSteps(step: numberOfSteps)
            updateColor(progressColor: progressColor ?? self.tintColor, nonProgressColor: nonProgressColor)
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable public var filledProgess: Int = 1 {
        didSet {
            if filledProgess >= numberOfSteps {
                filledProgess = numberOfSteps
                progress = .Full
            }
            if filledProgess <= 0 {
                filledProgess = 0
                progress = .Empty
            } else {
                progress = .Filled(num: filledProgess)
            }
            updateColor(progressColor: progressColor ?? tintColor, nonProgressColor: nonProgressColor)
        }
    }

    private var tip: CGFloat = 5
    private var progress: Progress = .Empty
    private var progressLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []

    private func updateColor(progressColor: UIColor, nonProgressColor: UIColor) {
        switch progress {
        case .Empty:
            progressLayers.forEach { $0.fillColor = nonProgressColor.cgColor }
        case let .Filled(num):
            progressLayers.dropFirst(num).forEach { $0.fillColor = nonProgressColor.cgColor }
            progressLayers.dropLast(progressLayers.count - num).forEach { $0.fillColor = progressColor.cgColor }
        case .Full :
            progressLayers.forEach { $0.fillColor = progressColor.cgColor }
        }
    }

    private func redrawSteps(step: Int) {
        progressLayers.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        progressLayers.removeAll()
        if step == 0 {
            let layer = CAShapeLayer()
            layer.frame = self.bounds
            progressLayers.append(layer)
        } else {
            var topLeft = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            let cgStep = CGFloat(step)
            let avaibleWidth = self.bounds.width - (2 * (cgStep - 1))
            let spacePerStep = avaibleWidth / cgStep
            let height = bounds.height
            let halfHeight = height / 2
            for i in 0..<step {

                let layer = CAShapeLayer()
                let bezier = UIBezierPath()
                bezier.move(to: topLeft)
                bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x + spacePerStep, y: topLeft.y))
                if i + 1 != step {
                    bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x + spacePerStep + tip, y: topLeft.y + halfHeight))
                }
                bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x + spacePerStep, y: topLeft.y + height))
                bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x, y: topLeft.y + height))
                if i != 0 {
                    bezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: topLeft.x + tip, y: topLeft.y + halfHeight))
                }
                bezier.close()
                layer.path = bezier.cgPath
                progressLayers.append(layer)
                self.layer.addSublayer(layer)

                topLeft.x = topLeft.x + spacePerStep + 2
            }
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        redrawSteps(step: numberOfSteps)
        updateColor(progressColor: progressColor ?? tintColor, nonProgressColor: nonProgressColor)
    }

}
```

All you have to do is take a UIView from the storyboard and make the custom class `StaticLoad`. You can specify the number of bars in the progress bar by changing the `numberOfSteps` property either by code or by the storyboard, and the fill of the bar by `filledProgress`

If you want a bigger arrow, just change the `tip` property, or specify another path for the bezierPath.

If you don't know, the `@IBDesignable` (it is recommended that if a class is designable it should be put in another framework rather than the same project due to the continuous compilation) allows the storyboard to render the view and the `@IBInspectable` allow to set the variable through the storyboard.

This is a working not-optimized example.